# How to parallelize an RDD of LinkedLists?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing, spark-streaming

I am developing an application in Spark, using the Spark Streaming Framework.
Right now my aim is to learn how parallellization works in Spark, and how I can use it to speed up my input data processing.
Here is my question: 
I have a DStream that in each Batch Interval has an RDD in which only one partition has data,  4 LinkedLists within that partition to be precise (I am not sure of how many partitions the RDD has exactly, perhaps 4 given the number of cores in my pc, since I am running in local mode).
I use the following to try and parallelize my RDD:

```
JavaDStream<LinkedList<Integer>>  rddWithPartitions=rddWithDataInOnePartition.repartition(4);
```

That is, with this, I intend to parallellize my RDD so that it has one LinkedList per partition, and not four in one single partition.

When I do a `rddWithPartitions.print()`, I indeed see what I think are 4 partitions filled with data, but when I go to the Spark UI, namely the Executors, I only see one, meaning (I think) that I am only using one Worker, and thus parallellization wasn't achieved.
I do have more than one task (although it is three and not four, as I thought would be the case), but I am not sure if I am using all four cores from my pc, each one processing one partition of my RDD.

How can I make sure that I achieved this parallellization? 
I hope I was not confusing.
Thank you so much.

Comment: would you care to explain how the title of your question is related to your question ?

Comment: @eliasah, as the  title states I would like to know how to parallellize an RDD. In the question itself I dive into the details about the parallellization itself, what I did to try and accomplish it, and why I think I failled to do so.
If I get the answer to what I wrote in the title, every problem in my question is addressed.

Comment: how do you check the partitions? `rddWithPartitions.print()` will print the content of the RDD. You could to do sthing like `rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((idx, part) => part.map(elem => (idx,elem))` to see what elements fall in which partition.

Comment: @maasg, thank you, I tried the rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex, after doing a foreachRDD in my DStream, and did a System.out.print(idx+ elm), but it didn't print anything...
One question though: I noticed that, when I had one LinkedList in four RDDs (one linkedlist per RDD), and then did a UNION of the 4 RDDs, the Spark UI showed that I was using 4 executors, and had 4 tasks, so the resulting RDD had 4 partitions like I wanted.
Do you know why it worked in this case, but not when I used repartition on one RDD with 4 LinkedLists?

Comment: If the print is empty, how do you know it has data?